# Why does IE9 not display javascript element properly unless "developer tools" is opened?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, flask, jinja2

I'm working with a form that will display a SelectField (id='databases') and only if the checkbox (id='alternate') is selected (using javascript) will the SelectField (id='alt_databases') display. This code works perfectly for Chrome/Firefox, but only works in IE9 when I open "developer tools". Code is based on flask, jinja2, and javascript. Does anyone have advice on this? I'm certain it's an IE specific issue.

Form:

```
<form method='post'>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.alternate.label }}<br>
    {{ form.alternate }}
    <table class='center' style='margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:70%'>
        <tr>
            <td class='media-left' style='display:none;'>
                {{ form.alt_databases.label }}<br>
                {{ form.alt_databases(size=20) }}<br>
            </td>
            <td class='media-right'>
                {{ form.databases.label }}<br>
                {{ form.databases(size=20) }}<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <p>{{ form.submit }}</p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
(function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('alternate'),
        source = document.getElementById('alt_databases');
        target = document.getElementById('databases');

    el.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (el.checked) {
            source.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            source.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Is that all there is to your JS? Many times when IE balks and then works when dev tools is open, there is an errant `console` call somewhere in your code. Check the console tab for errors/debug statements and that might help..... check your declaration of `target` the previous line ends in a  `;` not a `,`

Comment: one shim: `console=window.console||{log: String};`

Comment: There are no errors on the console tab and that is the entire content of my app.js file.

Comment: do you set a different doc mode in toolbar? do you memorize docmode?

Comment: Some DTD's will cause IE9 to expect the value of `el.checked` to be `"checked"`, though that ought to be a truthy value and still work. Might try outputting the value of `el.checked` on the page so you can check it without opening the developer tools. You could also confirm that your DTD is set to a version that will support the behavior you expect.

Comment: I believe I may have stumbled across the root of the issue. Before running "Start debugging" an old version of the javascript (with a console.log statment) showed up. Once I ran it, the new code showed up and seemed to work even without "developer tools" running (closed browser/deleted history, etc.). Is there an IE issue where javascript files are not refreshed up page refresh? And thanks @scrappedcola for the syntax fix.